# Error during zendfox installation, SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 (errno: 150)

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

During zendfox installation,

> `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
>   'zendfox.zf_member_forget_password_entity' (errno: 150)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

> If you re-create a table that was dropped, it must have a definition
>   that conforms to the foreign key constraints referencing it. It must
>   have the right column names and types, and it must have indexes on the
>   referenced keys, as stated earlier. If these are not satisfied, MySQL
>   returns error number 1005 and refers to error 150 in the error
>   message.